# Tag synonyms jdt and eclipse-jdt

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I lack the privilege to suggest an tag synonym, so I'm posting this question instead.

The tags [jdt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jdt/info) and [eclipse-jdt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse-jdt/info) refer to the exact same piece of software, they even have nearly identical descriptions (pasted from the [official](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.jdt) [website](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/)). I'd suggest making `jdt` a synonym of `eclipse-jdt`, just as [cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cdt/info) is a synonym of [eclipse-cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse-cdt/info).

Comment: I think making `jdt` a syn of the more explicit `eclipse-jdt` might be a better choice...

Comment: You are absolutely right, edited the question. I also checked for similiar tags, and cdt -> eclipse-cdt is handled the same way.